# jQuery get status stuck in pending. Never resolves

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, ember.js

Using this I get stuck in pending:

```
$.get("http://localhost:4500/image", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    })
```

But using the following the response comes back fine as a string:

```
function httpGet(theUrl){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

My node get request:

```
function getImage(req, res) {
    var file = fs.readFileSync('Boston.png')
    res.type('json')
    res.send({image: file.toString('base64')})
}

app.get('/image', function(req, res) {
    getImage(req, res)
})
```

It seems if I change my server allow origin to `http://stackoverflow.com` and run from here the ajax call works fine.

But if I run it on the `http://localhost:7357/4085/tests/index.html?hidepassed&coverage` (This is the ember test location) it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "pending"?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your first example is an async call, the second is synchronous. To make the first one synchronous, you can use $.ajax({ url: "http://....", method: "GET", async: false, success: function () {....} }); However, using synchronous calls to a server are not recommended for obvious reasons

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If I assign the first ajax call to a variable the `.status` is always pending, and `done,success,always` never get executed

@mhodges That's the reason I don't want to use httpGet. I don't wanna use a synchronous call

Comment: The ajax call results in a `Promise`... Please read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for how it works.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've looked there. The callback, success, done functions never get executed. I've tried all the examples on that page replacing the url with my own. But I never get a response

Comment: @Hillboy How are you testing the status? Are you testing it in a loop? You need to return to the browser's event loop to allow the asynchronous AJAX request to complete, then it will update `.status`.

Comment: @Barmar testing manually every now in then within the browser (it's been like 10 mins and still pending, so I must be doing something wrong.) Shouldn't the callback of the ajax request get executed when the Ajax request is complete? My posts work fine. Even on my get res.send(..) runs with no errors

Comment: Yes, it should. What do you see in the Network tab of DevTools?

Comment: The network tab I can see the actual response with proper format, looks fine there. Can't tell why the ajax callback never gets run